# Conversation + text-speech API in a single application

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, node-red, watson-conversation

I am using Node-Red to develop a application with both conversation and text to speech services. Goal is give text input and get both text and voice as output. I am able to create the application at node-red but facing trouble with how the template should be? Some one please help. 
P.S: the text to speech service is using input text from conversation output.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly the following should help point you in the right direction.

The string output from the conversation is stored on the `msg.payload.output.text` object. Using a function node between the `Conversation` node and the `Text to Speech` node will let you set:

`msg.payload = msg.payload.output.text`

as required by `Text to Speech`

Additionally, the function node may have multiple outputs so you can pass the string to `TTS` and wherever else you fancy, just edit the following parameter of the function node:

[image: outputs]

An example function node that flows from the Conversation node to Speech to Text would have the following code:

```
if (msg.payload.output && msg.payload.output.text) {
    msg.payload = msg.payload.output.text.join(' ');
} else {
    msg.payload = 'No response';
}
return msg;
```

The following flows from the Node-RED labs should help you:

[Text to Speech](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-red-labs/blob/master/starter-kits/interpreter/README.md)

[Conversation](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-red-labs/blob/master/starter-kits/ok_watson/README.md)

Comment: I am already using a function node inbetween conversation and Text-Speech node.

Comment: The function node consist of : msg.mydata.messageout = msg.payload;

msg.payload = {};
msg.payload.botresponse = msg.mydata;

return msg;

Comment: The Conversation node outputs it's message here:

`msg.payload.output.text` 

Speech to Text expects it's input here: 

`msg.payload`

So an example function node would do the following to flow from one to the other: 

````if (msg.payload.output && msg.payload.output.text) {
    msg.payload = msg.payload.output.text.join(' ');
} else {
    msg.payload = 'No response';
}

return msg;````

Comment: In current conversation template i am using this function: processOK(response) {
        console.log('003-001');
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.botresponse.messageout);
        console.log(response.botresponse.messageout.output.text);
        console.log(response.botresponse.messageout.context);
        chat('WATSON', response.botresponse.messageout.output.text); 
        $('#id_contextdump').data('convContext', response.botresponse.messageout.context);
      } ie:  conversation  output message is in: [link] msg.payload.botresponse.messageout.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you're looking to follow [this](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-red-labs/tree/master/basic_examples/conversation) tutorial? The code you have sent here is intended for client side use, and won't run in Node-RED. If you look at the bottom of the example there is a walkthrough about how to set up the Node-RED flow/template correctly. Please ensure you're using a conversation flow similar to the example [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-red-labs/blob/master/basic_examples/conversation/conversation_lab.json).

Comment: This is my current node flow. But i am unable to get voice output from it. I guess i'm missing something at the template code. Can someone help me on what am I going wrong at?

Comment: The template code doesn't affect audio output. If you would like to use the Conversation and Speech to Text API together, please follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-red-labs/tree/master/starter-kits/ok_watson) and let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Hi Chris,Thanks. I did go through that tutorial, but they are using Microphone and  Audio play node while i'm trying mine using HTTP post/get. Also i am attaching my current node-flow here. Can you please look into it and say what am i doing wrong. Appreciate a lot.